# SQL*Loader - Using sysdate if incoming value is blank

Tags: date, oracle11g, sql-loader, non-nullable

I am trying to create a control file for SQL*Loader script. I have a date column that is defined as NOT NULL.  I need to set-up the script to use current date, if the incoming value from the file is blank.  I tried a few ways  - some examples below - but I keep getting below error when running sql loader, but the format works if I do select from dual

How do I need to set it up in SQLLoader?

```
  PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS     POSITION(37:47) DATE "decode(length(trim(:PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS)), 11, to_date(:PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS,'yymmddHH24:MI'),to_date(sysdate,'yymmddHH24:MI'))",
  PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS     POSITION(37:47) DATE "NVL(Decode(:PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS,'00/00/0000',TO_DATE('01/01/2010','dd/mm/yyyy'),TO_DATE(:PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS,'dd/mm/yyyy')),TO_DATE('01/01/2010','dd/mm/yyyy'))",
```

oracle decode example ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
select decode(length(trim(:PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS)), 11, to_date(:PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS,'yymmddHH24:MI'),to_date(sysdate,'yymmddHH24:MI')) from dual
```

or

```
select NVL(Decode(:PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS,'00/00/0000',TO_DATE('01/01/2010','dd/mm/yyyy'),TO_DATE(:PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS,'dd/mm/yyyy')),TO_DATE('01/01/2010','dd/mm/yyyy')) from dual
```

works

What changes do I need to make to use it from a sql loader control file?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `to_date` in the ctl-file, so remove the explicit `DATE` specifier.

Also, you don't need to use use `decode` and `length`, `nvl` along with `trim` is the way to go.

Finally, `sysdate` is already a date, so you don't need to explicitely convert it into a date with `to_date`.

The following should work (not tested):

```
PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS POSITION(37:47) "nvl(to_date(trim(:PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS),'yymmddHH24:MI'),sysdate)",
```

Comment: Sorry, added the comments to above by mistake. I tested this NVL.  Thanks. I used the NVL part and now it is going further in terms of getting the ORA-00907 error. That error is now eliminated. I am still getting the below error when incoming data is spaces - column PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS. ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected . How can I resolve that part? Also one other question - the non-blank data has 2 digit year, so it is getting inserted as 20YY for all, how can I change this such that anything higher than 70 will be translated to 19YY?

Comment: We can help you better if you posted your `create table` statement your `*.ctl` file and a few records of sample data.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to set-up the script to use current date, if the incoming value from the file is blank.

If you get `NULL` value for the date column, then simply use `NVL` function to load `SYSDATE` instead.

`PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS     POSITION(37:47) DATE "NVL(:PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS, SYSDATE)"`

Don't be confused between `BLANK` and `NULL`. `00/00/0000` is neither blank nor null. If you are getting `00/00/0000` as the value, then use `DECODE`.

`PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS     POSITION(37:47) DATE "DECODE(:PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS, '00/00/0000', SYSDATE, :PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS)"`

Comment: Thanks. I used the NVL part and now it is going further in terms of getting the ORA-00907 error. That error is now eliminated. I am still getting the below error when incoming data is spaces - `column PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS. ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected `.  How can I resolve that part?

Comment: Also one other question - the non-blank data has 2 digit year, so it is getting inserted as 20YY for all, how can I change this such that anything higher than 70 will be translated to 19YY?

Comment: Use `RR` format instead of `YY`. `select to_date('01/01/72', 'dd/mm/rr') from dual`

Comment: @adbdkb, you sure the `NVL` throws `ORA-00907 `?

Comment: Wrap :PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS in TRIM(): "NVL(TRIM(:PROGRAM_CHANGE_TS), SYSDATE)".  That way NVL should see NULL instead of spaces.